# Progressbar и Flask

Tags: html, css, python, flask, progress-bar

Добрый день!
Суть вопроса в следующем:
Какими методами можно организовать передачу значения ProgressBar из Flask-приложения в зависимости от стадии выполнения цикла?

В целом модель проекта выглядит так:
Есть отдельное Python-приложение, работающее с базой данной. Оно выводит в командную строку состояние прогресса.

Есть отдельное Flask-приложение, которое выводит информацию из базы данных в виде таблицы.

Я ищу способ, которым можно организовать передачу состояния обновления из Python-скрипта в Flask-приложение, для дальнейшей передачи на Progressbar.

В сети нашел нечто похожее, но yield не дает работать циклам for в самом Python-скрипте.
Возможно я изобретаю велосипед - прошу подсказать, как это реализую нормальные разработчики :)
 Ну и собственно код примера:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/progress')
def progress():
    def generate():
        x = 0

        while x <= 100:
            yield "data:" + str(x) + "\n\n"
            x = x + 10
            time.sleep(0.5)

    return Response(generate(), mimetype= 'text/event-stream')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

И его темплэйт:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var source = new EventSource("/progress");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', event.data+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', event.data);
        $('.progress-bar-label').text(event.data+'%');
        if(event.data == 100){
            source.close()
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="progress" style="width: 50%; margin: 50px;">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
            <span class="progress-bar-label">0%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Streaming data with Python and Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13386681/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Проблема несколько сложнее, чем кажется на первый взгляд и стандартными методами Flask её решить трудно: между клиентом и сервером должно быть постоянное соединение + клиент и сервер через это соединение должны правильно взаимодействовать. К счастью, есть протокол WebSocket и клиентская библиотека SocketIo, которая позволяет взаимодействовать с сервером через этот протокол, а для Flask есть расширение Flask-SocketIo. В виртуальное окружение оно ставится командой `pip install flask-socketio`. Для работы так же требуется eventlet или gevent для обработки событий.

Когда всё будет установлено, серверный код будет выглядеть достаточно просто:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_socketio import emit
from flask_socketio import SocketIO


app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

thread = None
NS = "/test"

def progress_update():
    for i in range(5):
        socketio.sleep(1)
        socketio.emit("progress", {"text": 25 * i}, namespace=NS)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on("connect", namespace=NS)
def test_connect():
    print("connect")
    socketio.start_background_task(target=progress_update)


@socketio.on("disconnect", namespace=NS)
def test_disconnect():
    print("disconnect")
```

На клиенте, к сожалению, не сумел заставить код работать с jquery, зато с проблемой отлично справился vue.
Надо только подключить следующие скрипты:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

И обновить шаблон следующим образом:

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="progress" style="width: 50%; margin: 50px;">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"
            role="progressbar"
            v-bind:aria-valuenow="progress"
            aria-valuemin="0"
            aria-valuemax="100"
            v-bind:style="'width: '+progress+'%'"
        >
            <span class="progress-bar-label" v-text="progress + '%'"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span v-text="message"></span>
</div>

<script>
    let app = new Vue({
        el: "#test",
        data: {
            progress: 0,
            socket: null,
        },
        created: function() {
            socket = io.connect("http://" + document.domain + ":" + location.port + "/test");
            socket.on("progress", (msg) => {
                this.progress = msg.text;
            });
        },
    });
</script>
```

С виду vue работает достаточно просто: достаточно почитать [эту страницу](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/), чтобы понять, как работает приведённый пример. Для более глубокого ознакомления с WebSocket рекомендую прочитать [эту статью](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) и заглянуть на официальный репозиторий дополнения [Flask-SocketIo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO).

Стоит обратить внимание на то, что если обновить клиент до того, как прогресс бар заполнится, то метод `test_connect` выполнится ещё раз и будет два потока (two *threads*), которые эмитят (emit) событие `progress` с разными значениями, поэтому данную ситуацию нужно корректно обрабатывать.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ @montreal - то же самое с применением nuxt.js (фремворк для фреймворка vue.js)

```
<template>
  <div id="test">
    <div class="progress" style="width: 50%; margin: 50px;">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"
           role="progressbar"
           v-bind:aria-valuenow="progress"
           aria-valuemin="0"
           aria-valuemax="100"
           v-bind:style="'width: '+progress+'%'"
      >
        <span class="progress-bar-label" v-text="progress + '%'"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "AppProgressBar",
    data() { return {
      progress: 0,
      socket: "server",
    }
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log(this.$nuxtSocket)
      this.socket = this.$nuxtSocket({
        channel: '/test',
        name: "server"
      })
      console.log(this.socket)
      /* Listen for events: */
      this.socket
        .on("progress", (msg) => {
          this.progress = msg.text;
        })
    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Для этого надо имортировать (предвариельно установив) nuxt-socet-io в nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
.
.
.
    modules: [
    'nuxt-socket-io'// to enable progressbar
  ],
  io: { //socket IO options
    sockets: [ // Required
      { // At least one entry is required
        name: 'home',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        default: true,
      },
      { name: 'server', url: process.env.HOST_URL || 'http://localhost:5000'},
    ]
  },
.
.
.
}
```